# Retrieve records from relationship with query constraint

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent

I'm trying to retrieve all records from my `orders` table where an order is associated with a `supervisor`. `Orders` and `Supervisors` are associated with a `belongsToMany` relationship and have a pivot table.

So my code looks something like this:

```
$supervisor = User::where('phone_number', $request->msisdn)->first();
            $orders = Order::with(['supervisors' => function ($query) {
                $query->where('supervisor_id', $supervisor->id);
            }])->get();
```

I'm expecting to get a collection of orders which I'm then passing to a notification but instead get:

```
[2017-12-12 14:25:27] local.ERROR: Undefined variable: supervisor   

{"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined variable: supervisor
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you passing $supervisor into the blade as it's indicating that you are not.

Comment: Hey, not dealing with a blade variable. The answer below has answered the question correctly. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use USE to pass $supervisor into the function

```
$orders = Order::with(['supervisors' => function ($query) use($supervisor) {
                $query->where('supervisor_id', $supervisor->id);
            }])->get();
```

Comment: Hey, thanks this worked! Is there a way to also add a constraint to check something on the associated order table? So essentially to get all orders belonging to the supervisor, and where the order has X status?

Comment: Do you mean some like this:$orders = Order::where('status', '=', 'X')-> with(['supervisors' => function ($query) {
                $query->where('supervisor_id', $supervisor->id);
            }])->get();

Comment: Something like that, but it seems to be grabbing all the pending orders and not caring about the supervisor_id on the pivot table. So when I'm only expecting ~3 rows I'm getting about 20.

Comment: Trying to remember. Do you change the ->with to ->whereHas

Comment: So I've got the code below and it's returning a strpos() error and saying it was expecting a string but got an object. $orders = Order::where('status', '=', 'pending')->whereHas(['supervisors' => function ($query) { 
     $query->where('supervisor_id', $supervisor->id); 
    }])->get();

Comment: You have removed the use:  $orders = Order::where('status', '=', 'pending')->whereHas(['supervisors' => function ($query) use($supervisor) { $query->where('supervisor_id', $supervisor->id); }])->get();

Comment: Fixed it! Used this: $supervisor = User::where('phone_number', $request->msisdn)->first();
    $orders = Order::whereHas('supervisors', function ($query) use($supervisor) { 
     $query->where('supervisor_id', $supervisor->id); 
    })->where('status', '=', 'pending')->get();

Answer (score 0):

For those googling something similar, I used this and it worked:

```
$supervisor = User::where('phone_number', $request->msisdn)->first();
            $orders = Order::whereHas('supervisors', function ($query) use($supervisor) { 
                $query->where('supervisor_id', $supervisor->id); 
            })->where('status', '=', 'pending')->get();
```

Big thanks to p.wright for the help!